# MPAndroid Chart set X in a realtime graph

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I work for my school project on MPAndroidChart especially a realtime graph, i would like to display Time of the value.

I set a IndexAxisValueFormatter with a "getFormattedValue", it work but refresh every label and not just the last, I try to have for each entry in my graph a XLabel who show the time, I really don't know how to do that you're help would be welcome.

Code for create an entry and display it :

```
void creaGraph() {
    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    if (boxCO2.isChecked()) {
        A_CO2.add(new Entry(indice, listData.recup_data(indice - 1).getCO2()));
        LineDataSet setCO2 = new LineDataSet(A_CO2, "CO2");
        setCO2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        paramSet(setCO2);

        setCO2.setColor(Color.RED);
        setCO2.setCircleColor(Color.RED);
        dataSets.add(setCO2);
    }

    LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
    graph.setData(data);
    data.notifyDataChanged();
    graph.notifyDataSetChanged();
    graph.invalidate();

}
```

The override of getFormattedValue

```
@Override
  public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
      return listData.recup_data(GraphPage.indice - 1).getTemps();

  }
```

And a picture of my issue
[Every label are refresh when a new entry come](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1SmX.png)

Also, I see after the 7th values entry no longer have a time values

Comment: Oh you've right this work well when you use the right param... Big thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never use `value` in `getFormattedValue`. The string you construct there should be based on `value` or it will show the same thing for every axis entry.

Something like this:

```java
@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
   return makeDateStringAt(value);
}
```

For example, if you have a chart with axis values at 0, 1, 2, 3 then `getFormattedValue` will be called 4 times with `0f`, `1f`, `1f`, and `3f` as its arguments and you should use those inputs to create the appropriate string to show at those positions on the axis.